# Distributive axiom of Vector Spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

In the definition of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, it mentions that a set $V$ with $2$ operations, $+:V^2 \to V$ and $\cdot : \mathbb{R} \times V \to V$ satisfies some axioms, one of those axioms is  *Distribution of $+$ on $\cdot$*

$$ (p+q) \cdot v = p \cdot v + q \cdot v \ \  \forall p,q \in \mathbb{R}, v \in V$$

I don't get it, on the LHS the addition operator is different, it's an addition defined on real numbers but on the RHS it's the vector addition operator, defined on vectors of $V$ how did it go from being one operator to a completely different operator?

Comment: That is the objective of defining a property.  It is often said that such operations are "compatible."

Comment: Well, presumably they give you examples where this occurs, yes?  Ordinary coordinate arithmetic, being the most standard.

Comment: You stated that you don't get it. What is there to get? Is there something in that equality that doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware, that the $+$ on the lefthand side is different from the one on the right, this might look strange, and therefore on some textbooks, a difference between $+_{Vector}$ and $+_{\mathbb{R}}$ is made. The defintion then is the following:

$(p +_\mathbb{R} q) \cdot v = (p \cdot v) +_{Vector} (q \cdot v)$

For example, consider a vector space known from high school, such as $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ before considering more abstract ones. As here the intuition of an addition of vectors is more intuitive than in the general case, this should give you a feeling of what is meant by the definition.

Comment: Perhaps OP is of the view that when the two "additions" are actually different operations, one shouldn't use the term, "distributive law".

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes kind of, because when you say you're distributing $+_{\mathbb{R}}$ over $\cdot$, you didn't distribute $+_{\mathbb{R}}$ you distributed something different.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics there is usually the idea (expanding a bit @Azif00's comment) of a "function respecting the structure". Staying away for a moment from the overwhelming structure of vector spaces (which are in fact a combination of an algebraic structure and an action of another - complex - algebraic structure on the former), let's consider a couple $ (S,f) $ of a set $ S $ and an *operation* $ f\colon S^n\to S $, for some $ n\in\mathbb N $. A mapping $ \phi\colon S\to T $ form $ S $ to another set $ T $ endorsed with a function $ g $ of the same kind of $ f $ is said to *respect* the function $ f $ if
$$
\phi\left(f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)=g\left(\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_n)\right)
$$
In other words, if $ \phi^n $ is the function $ S^n\to T^n $ mapping a $ n $-uple $ (x_1,\dots,x_n) $ of elements of $ S $ to the $ n $-uple $ \left(\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_n)\right) $, then the function $ \phi $ *respect* $ f $ if the following diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^n @>{\phi^n}>> T^n\\
@VVfV @VVgV\\
S @>{\phi}>> T
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

Now, turning back to vector spaces, we're considering pairs $ (V,{+}) $, where $ V $ is a set, and $ {+}\colon V\times V\to V $  is a *binary* operation on $ V $, satisfying the (commutative) group axioms; and pairs $ (\mathbb K, {+_{\mathbb K}}, {\cdot_{\mathbb K}}) $, satisfying the field axioms. The "distributivity" now asserts that the "scaling" operation $ \mathbb K\times V\to V $ respects... Let's turn back for a moment.

Every function $ S_1\times S_2\to T $ can be seen as a function $ S_1\to T^{S_2} $ , where $ T^{S_2} $ is the set of all functions $ S_2\to T $. The scaling function $ \mathbb K\times V\to V$ is thus the same thing as a function $ \mathbb K\to V^V $: **does this guy respect $ {+_{\mathbb k}} $ (considering the two structures $ (\mathbb K, {+_{\mathbb K}}) $ and $ (V^V, {+}) $)?**